# How to make this code compatible with firefox browser

Tags: javascript

I have a question about multi browser compatibility. I want to use the event.target instead event.srcElement in the following code to make it work for firefox.

I have used target = event.target || event.srcElement. It is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function jumptoPopupMenuItem(theMenuID) 
{                
  if (event.srcElement.className == "RightClickMenuItems") 
  {
    if (event.srcElement.getAttribute("url") != null)
    {        
      var strParameters = "";                                    
      if (theMenuID == "mnuAppointmentMenu")
      {
        strParameters = "AppointmentNumber=" + m_strAppointmentTypeYearNumber;
      }
      else if (theMenuID == "mnuAvailableHourMenu")
      {
        strParameters = "PreFillLanguageID=" + m_nLanguageID;
        strParameters = strParameters + "&PreFillInterpreterID=" + m_nInterpreterID;
        strParameters = strParameters + "&PreFillDateOfService=" + m_dtDateOfService;
      }
      if (event.srcElement.getAttribute("target") != null)
      {
        var PopupWindow = window.open(
            event.srcElement.url + strParameters, 
            event.srcElement.getAttribute("target"));
        PopupWindow.focus();
      }
      else
      {
        window.location = event.srcElement.url;
      }
    }
    hidePopupMenu(theMenuID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Append code where you register event handler for element (e.g. `attachEvent`, `addEventListener`).

Comment: can you give me some more details. For firefox comapatibilty. I should change srcElement to target.because srcElement will not be recognized by Firefox. can you provide me solution

Comment: your code (`target = event.target||event.srcElement`) is valid, but function `jumptoPopupMenuItem()` must use `event` object to work properly. In IE you can use global `window.event` object (or simply `event`), but in FF `window.event` is not defined. Read my answer for some explanations and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Some standard ways to register event handlers with compatibility (very simplified code):

HTML:

```
<button onclick="eventHandlerFunc(event)" />
<!-- better to register as: -->
<button onclick="eventHandlerFunc.call(this,event)" />
```

JavaScript (addEventListener or attachEvent):

```
if (window.addEventListener) someElem.addEventListener("click",eventHandlerFunc,false);
else if (window.attachEvent) someElem.attachEvent("onclick",eventHandlerFunc);
```

JavaScript (element property):

```
someElem.onclick = eventHandlerFunc;
```

Where `eventHandlerFunc()` function defined as:

```
function eventHandlerFunc(event) { // or var eventHandlerFunc = function(event) {
  event = event||window.event; // can be needed only for IE6-IE8
                               // because `event` parameter hide `event` global
                               // variable (`window.event`)
  var target = event.target||event.srcElement
}
```

*NOTE: If needed compatibility for `this` variable additional code must be added.*

If then needed to use `event` variable (defined inside `eventHandlerFunc()` as parameter) inside other functions you must send it to these functions:

```
function eventHandlerFunc(event) {
  event = event||window.event; // can be needed only for IE6-IE8
  /*
  ...
  */
  jumptoPopupMenuItem(event,theMenuID);
}

function jumptoPopupMenuItem(event,theMenuID) {
}
```